# Как сделать прелоадер для input?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Есть обычный input:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn pull-right" value="Add">
```

Как сделать прелоадер для input, чтобы показывался div:

```
<div ng-show="!AILoading" class="name"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может как-то так:

```js
angular
  .module('App', ['ngActivityIndicator'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$activityIndicator', '$scope', MainCtrl]);

function MainCtrl($activityIndicator, $scope) {
  $scope.start = function() {
    $activityIndicator.startAnimating();
  };

  $scope.stop = function() {
    $activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
  };
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    <div ng-show="AILoading">Loading...</div>
    <div ng-show="!AILoading">
      <input name="myinput" value="myvalue">
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn" ng-click="start()">Start</a>
    <a href="" class="btn" ng-click="stop()">Stop</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо данные берутся дополнительным запросом. Тогда можно в контроллере изначально `$scope.AILoading = false`, а когда данные подгрузятся:

```
    $http.get(path, params).success(function (resp) {
        //какой-то код
        $scope.AILoading = true;
    });
```

Или, возможно, Вам нужно при сабмите `ng-submit="AILoading = false"`, а при загрузке данных возвращать в `true`

Comment: Я использую плагин https://github.com/voronianski/ngActivityIndicator Только вот не удается его засунуть в div